# Serving a staging and production site via nginx?

Tags: django, nginx

I am currently serving a Django site using the following nginx configuration at somesite.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name somesite.com;

    location /static {
        alias /home/me/sites/somesite.com/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/somesite.com.socket;
    }
}
```

I'd like to also serve a staging site at staging.somesite.com . How would I serve both sites using nginx? Would I need two nginx config files, or one? Can I just add another `server_name staging.somesite.com;` block?

Comment: The tools are out there that make it easy to quickly stand up a temporary staging environment in a cloud. I'm talking vagrant and ansible, for example. You might consider that route.

Answer (score 1):

Serving staging and production with the same webserver? sound like a very bad idea.

consider to setup and standalone staging server with the same configuration as production don't mix between them.

anytime anywhere on any application you build don't share nothing between staging and production servers, production is real money server staging is for developers and QA to do their work.

Comment: The advice is very fine, but you still don't answer his question.
I need to do the same thing and for my testing purposes that is totally fine, regardless of the impact.
But seeing your answer - doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: This is good advice, but in no way answers the question. This would be better as a comment, and not an answer.